# Authorization in a Composite WPF / Silverlight application

Tags: c#, java, web-services, security, prism

The [Composite UI application guidance](http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/ff921088%28PandP.20%29.aspx) states that it does not cover Authentication and authorization.

We are currently designing a system which may have Silverlight webparts created in Composite UI application framework that talk to web services. These may be Java Web Services on a services bus.

In this scenario what is the best way to handle Authentication and Authorization?